# Saving Refactor Layer?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I used the toolbox to refactor attribute field names which worked well. However I then seem to have lost the changes as the layer was only a temporary scratch file.

How do I save to make these changes permanent for my project?

Answer (score 2):

In the QGIS (3.6.3) Layers pane, right click the temporary layer and: **Export > Save Features As..**

This will open a new window which will allow you (with many options) to permanently save the layer in the output format of your choice.

Comment: Hi there. I did as you suggested but get this error message "Export to vector file failed. Error: Creation of layer failed (OGR error: Failed to create file Enc Bound Shape1.shp: Permission denied)" I also tried with spatialite and that failed as well. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: That error message happens when you type the file name where you should input a complete file path. Eg, when trying to save shape1.shp to the file C:\Documents, you should type C:\Documents\shape1.shp. Or better yet, use the `...` button next to the text bar to navigate to the correct folder through the file explorer interface.